# Equivalent to CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there an equivalent to `CGRectIntersectsRect` that would be something more along the lines of points intersecting... I'm making a game and RectIntersectsRect works for what I want it to do but it looks bad because sometimes the corner of the one object will intersect the corner of the other and it will call the method, and you can barely see that the two objects touched, so it looks like it just glitches. Is there a CGPointIntersectsPoint or something along the lines of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CGRectContainsPoint to see if one of your rectangle contains a corner of the other, but you will get the same issue.

You can look for the intersection of the two rectangles using  CGRectIntersection. It will give you an other CGRect, which represents the area in common from your two rectangles. From this rectangle, you can check width and height to see if the intersection is "big enough"

```
CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(rect1, rect2);
if (CGRectGetWidth(intersection) > kHorizontalThreshold || CGRectGetHeight (intersection) > kVerticalThreshold)
{
     // call your intersection method here
}
```

Comment: This seems like it could be helpful. I'm just trying to figure out how I would use it. In my game, the lion jumps on platforms. The lion is 32x56px and platforms range in size, one for example is 110x65. So with the helpful template you've provided, say I wanted to have it so the intersection method was only called if the lion intersected an invisible rectangle inside of the platform that was 75% of the size. How would I input that into the template ^ do I replace kHorizontalThreshold and Vertical to the dimensions?

Comment: From what you say, the 75% is width-related because you want to know if enough width of the lion is on the platform. Lets focus only on width to simplify the problem. You have two cases : if the platform is big enough (imagine 1000px), then you only have to check if (CGRectGetWidth(intersection) >= 0.75*lionWidth). But if the platform width is lower than 75% of lionWidth, you only have to check if the lion is on every single pixel on this platform, so your other test will be to check if (CGRectGetWidth(intersection) == platformWidth)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`CGRectContainsPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17143). If you want to just compare two points use [`CGPointEqualToPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17141).

You can't really have a point intersecting another point as they're two exact points in space. The only way they can "intersect" is by being equal.